# Android-On updating a row in sql database, whole database gets the same values

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

```
/**
 * Updates the data at the given selection and selection arguments, with the new ContentValues.
 */
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case TASKS:
            return updatetask(uri, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);
        case TASKS_ID:
            // For the task_ID code, extract out the ID from the URI,
            // so we know which row to update. Selection will be "_id=?" and selection
            // arguments will be a String array containing the actual ID.
            selection = TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            return updatetask(uri, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Update is not supported for " + uri);
    }
}

/**
 * Update tasks in the database with the given content values. Apply the changes to the rows
 * specified in the selection and selection arguments (which could be 0 or 1 or more tasks).
 * Return the number of rows that were successfully updated.
 */
private int updatetask(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // If the {@link TaskEntry#COLUMN_task_NAME} key is present,
    // check that the name value is not null.
    if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME)) {
        String name = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME);
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("task requires a name");
        }
    }


    // If the {@link TaskEntry#COLUMN_task_GENDER} key is present,
    // check that the gender value is valid.
    if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DATE)) {
        String date = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DATE);
        if (date == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter valid date.");
        }
    }

    // If the {@link TaskEntry#COLUMN_task_WEIGHT} key is present,
    // check that the weight value is valid.
    if (values.containsKey(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TIME)) {
        // Check that the weight is greater than or equal to 0 kg
        String time = values.getAsString(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TIME);
        if (time == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("task requires valid time ");
        }
    }

    // If there are no values to update, then don't try to update the database
    if (values.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Otherwise, get writeable database to update the data
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // Perform the update on the database and get the number of rows affected
    int rowsUpdated = database.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

Above is the code for my content provider update method.

```
/**
 * Get user input from editor and save new task into database.
 */
private void saveTask() {
    // Read from input fields
    // Use trim to eliminate leading or trailing white space
    String nameString = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String dateString = mDateEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String timeString = mTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String locationString = mLocationEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    if (mNotifySwitch.isChecked()){
        mToNotify = TaskContract.TaskEntry.NOTIFY_YES;
    }

    if (mCurrenttaskUri == null &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(nameString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString) &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(timeString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(locationString)) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
    // and task attributes from the editor are the values.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME, nameString);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DATE, dateString);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TIME, timeString);

    String location = null;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(locationString)) {
        location = locationString;
    }
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_LOCATION, location);
    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.NOTIFY_LOCATION, mToNotify);

    // Insert a new row for task in the database, returning the ID of that new row.
    // long newRowId = db.insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    if (mCurrenttaskUri == null) {
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
        if (newUri == null) {
            // If the new content URI is null, then there was an error with insertion.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inserting task failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Inserting task successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, null, null);
        if (rowsAffected == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Updating task failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Updating task successful!.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, above is the code for providing content values.
Querying and Inserting are working properly, but, when I update one row in my app, all the rows gets filled up with the same updated data.
Please help..
Below is the code for table creation.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the tasks table
    String SQL_CREATE_TASKS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_LOCATION + " TEXT, "
            + TaskContract.TaskEntry.NOTIFY_LOCATION + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    // Execute the SQL statement
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);
}
```

Need immediate help, please respond